# C-Norm of multiple derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

We're calculating Trapezoid and Simpson's rule estimates for definite integrals.  For the error, we need the C-norm of the first - fourth derivatives.  How do I enter this into Mathematica?  As of right now I've been using other calculators to find the max value of the derivatives on an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you put a more precise question.
I assume in the following, that you are looking for the maximum of a function and its derivatives over some interval.
As an example I choose "Sin" and the interval {-1,1}. With this assumptions:

```
f[x_] = Sin[x];
funs = Through[{f, f', f'', f''', f''''}[x]];
Print["MaxValues= ", MaxValue[{#, -1 <= x <= 1}, x] & /@ funs // N]
Plot[funs, {x, -1, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]